# Javascript multi click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need some help i have the link of the output of what i have done below using javascript and HTML.
http://i.imgbox.com/adlMVTIx.jpg
What i need to do is when i click on one circle the other circle should be disabled and the one that is clicked should be active..the problem now is that when click on a circle and click another one..both stays active..

This is the javascript code i have done so far,Please help me out guys really appreciate it!

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <!--scripts-->
    <script src="jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!--styles-->
    <link href="styles/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#c1').click(function () {

                //$(this).css('background-color', '#005aa8');
                $(this).css('width', '190px');
                $(this).css('height', '190px');
                $(this).css('top', 243 - ((190 - 125) / 2));
                $(this).css('left', 335 - ((190 - 125) / 2));
                $(this).removeClass("blink");
                $(this).css('background-image', 'URL(assets/images/blue_back.png)');

            })

            $('#c2').click(function () {

                //$(this).css('background-color', '#005aa8');
                $(this).css('width', '190px');
                $(this).css('height', '190px');
                $(this).css('top', 898 - ((190 - 125) / 2));
                $(this).css('left', 336 - ((190 - 125) / 2));
                $(this).removeClass("blink");
                $(this).css('background-image', 'URL(assets/images/1.png)');

            })


            $('#c3').click(function () {

                //$(this).css('background-color', '#005aa8');
                $(this).css('width', '190px');
                $(this).css('height', '190px');
                $(this).css('top', 470 - ((190 - 125) / 2));
                $(this).css('left', 100 - ((190 - 125) / 2));
                $(this).removeClass("blink");
                $(this).css('background-image', 'URL(assets/images/2.png)');

            })


            $('#c4').click(function () {

                //$(this).css('background-color', '#005aa8');
                $(this).css('width', '190px');
                $(this).css('height', '190px');
                $(this).css('top', 800 - ((190 - 125) / 2));
                $(this).css('left', 570 - ((190 - 125) / 2));
                $(this).removeClass("blink");
                $(this).css('background-image', 'URL(assets/images/3.png)');

            })


            $('#c5').click(function () {

                //$(this).css('background-color', '#005aa8');
                $(this).css('width', '190px');
                $(this).css('height', '190px');
                $(this).css('top', 165 - ((190 - 125) / 2));
                $(this).css('left', 1287 - ((190 - 125) / 2));
                $(this).removeClass("blink");
                $(this).css('background-image', 'URL(assets/images/5.png)');

            })


            $('#c6').click(function () {

                //$(this).css('background-color', '#005aa8');
                $(this).css('width', '190px');
                $(this).css('height', '190px');
                $(this).css('top', 308 - ((190 - 125) / 2));
                $(this).css('left', 1450 - ((190 - 125) / 2));
                $(this).removeClass("blink");
                $(this).css('background-image', 'URL(assets/images/6.png)');

            })


            $('#c7').click(function () {

                //$(this).css('background-color', '#005aa8');
                $(this).css('width', '190px');
                $(this).css('height', '190px');
                $(this).css('top', 600 - ((190 - 125) / 2));
                $(this).css('left', 1390 - ((190 - 125) / 2));
                $(this).removeClass("blink");
                $(this).css('background-image', 'URL(assets/images/7.png)');

            })


            $('#c8').click(function () {

                //$(this).css('background-color', '#005aa8');
                $(this).css('width', '190px');
                $(this).css('height', '190px');
                $(this).css('top', 820 - ((190 - 125) / 2));
                $(this).css('left', 1720 - ((190 - 125) / 2));
                $(this).removeClass("blink");
                $(this).css('background-image', 'URL(assets/images/8.png)');

            })
        })

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="c1" class="circle blink">
        </div>
        <div id="c2" class="circle blink">
        </div>
        <div id="c3" class="circle blink">
        </div>
        <div id="c4" class="circle blink">
        </div>
        <div id="c5" class="circle blink">
        </div>
        <div id="c6" class="circle blink">
        </div>
        <div id="c7" class="circle blink">
        </div>
        <div id="c8" class="circle blink">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my css code

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#main
{
    width: 1920px;
    height: 1080px;
    background-image: URL('../assets/images/iwmi-bg.jpg');
}
.circle
{
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    border: 5px solid #fdb219; /*box-shadow: 5px 5px #000;*/
    text-align: center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center; }

@keyframes blink {  
    0% {  width:60px; height:60px; left: 335px; top: 243px; }
    100% { width:65px; height:65px; left: 333.5px; top: 241.5px;  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    0% {  width:60px; height:60px;left: 335px; top: 243px; }
    100% { width:65px; height:65px;left: 333.5px; top: 241.5px;  }
}

.blink {
    -webkit-animation: blink .75s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: blink .75s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: blink .75s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: blink .75s linear infinite;
    animation: blink .75s linear infinite;
} 

@keyframes blink1 {  
    0% {  width:60px; height:60px; left: 335px; top: 243px; }
    100% { width:65px; height:65px; left: 332.5px; top: 240.5px;  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes blink1 {
    0% {  width:60px; height:60px;left: 336px; top: 898px; }
    100% { width:65px; height:65px;left: 333.5px; top: 895.5px;  }
}

.blink1 {
    -webkit-animation: blink1 .75s linear infinite;
    -moz-animation: blink1 .75s linear infinite;
    -ms-animation: blink1 .75s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: blink1 .75s linear infinite;
    animation: blink1 .75s linear infinite;
} 

#c1
{
    left: 335px;
    top: 243px;
}
#c2
{
  left: 336px;
  top: 898px;  
}
#c3
{
  left: 100px;
  top: 470px;  
}
#c4
{
  left: 570px;
  top: 800px;  
}
#c5
{
  left: 1287px;
  top: 165px;  
}
#c6
{
  left: 1450px;
  top: 308px;  
}
#c7
{
  left: 1390px;
  top: 600px;  
}
#c8
{
  left: 1720px;
  top: 820px;  
}
```

Comment: add the css of circle blink too

Comment: Argh... that is some muddy code.  You are adding WAY TOO MUCH css into your javascript.  Nothing is being calculated that couldn't be processed before hand.  ALL of that stuff belong in a css class.

Comment: what exactly is making the circle look inactive, `$(this).removeClass("blink");` ?

Comment: when one circle is clicked the other should be inactive thats what i need, any help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved all that css to where it belongs.  Now look how beautifully simple the javascript is.

http://jsfiddle.net/8NN4x/

jQuery:

```
var $circles = $('.circle','#main');
$circles.on('click',function(){
    $circles.removeClass('clicked');
    $(this).addClass('clicked').removeClass('blink');    
});
```

Comment: Im confused i aded my css in the question can u check that,is it ok?

Comment: Close.  The few items at the bottom  #c1 etc should look like what I have in the fiddle.